# How to apply hermite InterpolatingPolynomial?

Tags: programming, interpolation

I found that to do hermite InterpolatingPolynomial
I need to write:

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[{{{1}, 2, 3}, {{2}, 6, 7, 8}}, x]
```

however,i need to apply it on a table:

```
 Table [{xi = a + (b - a)/n i ,  N[Round[10^7  f [xi]]/10^7],  
N[ N[Round[10^7  f2 [xi]]/10^7]]}, {i, 0, n}]  ]
```

so how can i do that?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you have it close, just need an extra `{}` on the `x` term:
( making up a simple example..)

```
n = 4; a = 0; b = 1; f[x_] := 10^12 Sin[2 x] ; f2[x_] := 10^12 Cos[x] ;
poly = InterpolatingPolynomial[
   Table[{{xi = a + (b - a)/n i}, N@Round[ f[xi], 10^7], 
     N@Round[f2[xi], 10^7]}, {i, 0, n}], x] // Simplify
```

> 0.+ 1.*10^12 x + 6.76392*10^13 x^2 - 7.54631*10^14 x^3 + 
>    3.6613*10^15 x^4 - 9.58558*10^15 x^5 + 1.44937*10^16 x^6 - 
>    1.26549*10^16 x^7 + 5.91826*10^15 x^8 - 1.14596*10^15 x^9

```
Plot[{f[x], poly}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.01], {Thin, Red}}]
```

[image]

I cleaned things up using the 2 arg form of `Round`.

You should notice I deliberately fed it the wrong derivative just for illustration, otherwise you get a perfect fit for this example.

Edit: if you already have the table of the form

```
 table={{x1,f[x1],fp[x1]},{x2,f[x2],fp[x2]},...}
```

you do like this to add in the `{ }`:

```
 InterpolatingPolynomial[{List@First@#, Sequence @@ Rest@#} & /@ table, x]
```